# Chrome Extension js: Sharing functions between background.js and popup.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Suppose I have a JavaScript function `foo()` which I want to execute in both the background and in `popup.html`.

For example: it is executed every hour in the background of my Chrome extension, but can also be activated by the user from the popup menu (`popup.html`) on a button click.

I currently have a `global.js` script which defines `foo()` and when I include calls to `foo()` in my `popup.js` document, they execute without issue. (If I include both scripts in `popup.html`)

However, when I try to access `foo()` inside `background.js`, the calls do not execute (even if `global.js` is included in the "background" "manifest.json" extension file:

```
"background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["background.js", "global.js"]
},
```

Is there a convenient way to share functions between `background.js` and `popup.js` (without copying the entire function into each)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The background scripts are loaded in the order specified in the manifest file. Simply load the file with common code before your background script as follows:

```
"background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["global.js", "background.js"]
},
```

Instead of duplicating the code in the popup, you can also use [`chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage) from the popup to access functions/variables of the [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages), e.g. `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().myFunction();`.

Comment: Great, the whole reason I was looking for your solution was to improve DRY. Your second hint helps even more!! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can also call functions from other scripts almost as if you had imported them all directly. You can do this by using constructors, and custom prototypes.

First add the background scripts to the mainfest, in order of access, as well as linked as scripts in our popup.html before the closing *body tag*:

**manifest.json**

```
...
"background": {
"persistent": false,
"scripts": [
  "foo.js",
  "bg.js"
]},
...
```

In the file foo.js we create our object prototype. I'm using a module pattern, because we want it to be private otherwise:

**foo.js**

```
(() => {
  console.log('foo loaded');       // check that the script has loaded
  window.test = window.test || {}; // check for or create the object

  test.FooFunc = function() {      // setup a constructor to hold defaults
    this.foo = 'bar',
    this.time = '15000'
  }

  test.FooFunc.prototype = {       // add our prototype with a single method
    callConsole: (text) => {
      console.log('FooFunc method loaded from ' + text);
    }
  }
})();
```

From the bg.js file we can call this function constantly by instantiating a new *test* object.

**bg.js**

```
(() => {
  console.log('bg loaded');            // check that the script has loaded
  var testProto = new test.FooFunc;    // instantiate new test object

  testProto.callConsole('Background!');
})();
```

After loading the files, and as soon as the Icon is clicked the Pop-up opens, the scripts fire, including our function. You should see something like this in your console:

```
foo loaded
bg loaded
FooFunc method loaded from Background!
```

**Using Multiple Background Scripts**

Of course we can continue to add more scripts into the mix by simply adding them to the *background* script list, and popup.html before the bg.js, *in the order you want them to be accessed**. Once added, make new prototypes to the *test* object from the new scripts in the same manor, and then adding methods to each (test.Prefs is a great one to make).

**Scripts are loaded in order they are called, so if the prototype is not created before a script that wants to access it, it will not be able to find the new prototype. Any script can access the prototypes as long as they are created before those scripts are called.*

For a great example of this in a use-case scenario, you can check out [Chrome's Buildbot Monitor](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:build). It not only shows a great process of working with multiple scripts privately, but also how you can use a single object to hold multiple settings, prototypes, and methods for your extension to access.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding the scripts as part of the `background` section of your `manifest.json`, you have to access the contents in those scripts via the `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(callback)` API (which is currently `preferred to chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`).

For example, in `popup.js` or elsewhere in your extension:

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(backgroundPageWindow) {
  // Do stuff here that requires access to the background page.
  // E.g. to access the function 'myFunction()'
  console.log("Calling myFunction() " + backgroundPageWindow.myFunction());
});
```

For more details, see the [getBackgroundPage documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage) and the [event pages docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) (which explain that `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` is deprecated).